# Adding JVM args AND jacoco-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, jacoco

Just wanted to know if it's usefull to start the jacoco agent using the maven plugin and to add some arguments to surefire ? Does it start Jacoco twice ?

Example :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>           
        </plugin>
```

And

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<argLine>-javaagent:${sonar.jacoco.jar}=destfile='${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}'</argLine>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They provide [Maven usage example](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom.xml), so it seems additional arguments for Surefire are not needed.

Comment: additional arguments for Surefire are definitely not needed

Comment: When I don't add the surefire argument Jenkins seems not to find the Jacoco package :( Did I do something wrong ? ._.

Comment: I have the same issue, Depado. have you figured that out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your `${jacoco.version}` is, but the following snippet worked for me.

You don't need to provide additional arguments for the surefire plugin.

The version has to be one that is declared in the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin)( Assuming that you didn't install the dependency locally or use some other/custom repository):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.7.201204190339</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```